# C# updating a dictionary in a different class

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, dictionary, networking

I have a dictionary which holds data and I have threads which handle concurrent client requests. I want some of the client requests to change the values in the dictionary when needed but not sure how to fix scope issues when dealing with threads and classes.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
class Program 
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> teamInformation = new Dictionary<string, int>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    runserver();
}

static void runServer()
{
    //connection stuff

    while(true)
    {
        threadRequest = new Handler();
        Thread t = new Thread (() => threadRequest.clientInteraction(connection));
        t.Start();
    }
}

class Handler
{
    public void clientInteraction(Socket connection)
    {
        //does stuff

        teamInformation.Add(pTeamName, 0); //where pTeamName has been read from the client input
    }
}
```

How would I go about making changes to the Dictionary (which needs to be accessible by all threads) in the Handler class?

I don't know how to index the threads either or at least flag them in the dictionary entries. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to send a specific value to a specific thread.

Comment: Use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @stuartd This seems exactly what I need thanks. I'm looking into it now. But would I need to declare the Concurrent Dictionary each time in the Handler class? Would that edit the dictionary with the same name for all threads. Or simply just create multiple concurrent dictionaries relevant to each thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with .NET 4.0 collections have a better handle on thread safety. You can have many threads write to them with no problems. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx). The same goes for multiple readers.

The problem lies when you have both operations happening at the same time as enumerating through a collection that gets modified is a problem.

A better alternative would be to use a datatype that supports thread safety such as ConcurrentDictionary which is thread safe and allows readers and writers at the same time. (Excludes some members accessed through interfaces that ConcurrentDictionary implements).

The change is most likely a drop in change for you from:
`public static Dictionary<string, int> teamInformation = new Dictionary<string, int>();` to `public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> teamInformation = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx for greater depth

EDIT: Here is an example of it's usage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> teamInformation = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start();

            Console.WriteLine("ConcurrentDictionary contains : " + teamInformation.Count);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Start()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var threadRequest = new Handler();
                var thread = new Thread(() => threadRequest.ClientInteraction(teamInformation));
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Handler
    {
        public void ClientInteraction(ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> teamInformation)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                teamInformation.AddOrUpdate(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), i, (key, val) => val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe you can just pass it right to your thread. This code simply spawns a load of threads and creates a new entry for each.

However by using AddOrUpdate you can specify that if your key (or team) exists you can update the existing entry with the third Func param.

Other options for sharing the property would be through a static class or singleton. You may want to consider what will be using this property and your current architecture to see where to slot it in.

Comment: I see how using a concurrent dictionary is better when using threading and have updated my code so many thanks for the tip! However I'm now struggling to understand where to declare the new dictionary. SImply replacing the old dictionary with the concurrent dictionary still flags up scope issues when trying to add values in the Handler class. Good ol' "dictionary does not exist in the current context".

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example showing one way of implementing the code.

Answer (score -1):

You could put the dictionary as paramter in the start function like:

```
Thread t = new Thread (() => threadRequest.clientInteraction(connection));
    t.Start(ref teamInformation);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Important is to use call by reference so you can access the same dictionary and not a copy. But im not sure if the compiler will accept the 'ref' here